# Integer homology of double loop space of odd-dimensional sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology, loop-spaces

I have checked everything "homology of loop spaces"-like, but was not able to find what is $H_*(\Omega^2S^3, \mathbb{Z})$. Therefore I ask you how to compute that?

Comment: You know it mod p for all primes, and it's not hard to figure out the Bockstein. Then there's a theorem of Cohen that the only p-torsion you'll see will have exact order p, so that should be enough. If I have time later I'll try to write out what happens.

Comment: I guess Cohen says that the $E_{\infty}$-page (which as I said before is also the $E_2$-page) of the Bockstein sseq will look like $\mathbb{F}_p[y]$ where $|y|=1$? (yeah it's weird that we have a polynomial algebra without graded commutativity, and I'm not quite sure I'm parsing his result properly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are homology isomorphisms $K(Br,1)\to \Omega^2_0 S^2$ and $\Omega^2 S^3\to \Omega^2_0 S^2$, so you are really asking about the homology of the stable braid group $Br$ (the colimit of the natural inclusions $Br_n\hookrightarrow Br_{n+1}$).

As expected there is no neat description with integral coefficients, but much is known. You'll find a nice summary in Section 4 of [this paper](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Vershinin/hobr.pdf) of Vershinin .

Answer (score 6):

The calculation you want is described in detail in Joe Neisendorfer's book *Algebraic Methods in Unstable Homotopy Theory*, Cambridge University Press, 2010.   In particular, the Eilenberg--Moore spectral sequence collapses to give that $H_*(\Omega^2 S^3;\mathbb Z) = Cotor_*^{\mathbb Z[y]}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)$.  By calculating mod p, and then using the very simple Bockstein spectral sequence, he shows in Corollary 10.26.5, that $p$ annihilates the $p$--torsion for all primes $p$.  Thus $H_*(\Omega^2 S^3;\mathbb Z)_{(p)}$ is a graded $\mathbb Z/p$ vector space (above dimension 1) whose Poincare series could easily be worked out from $H_*(\Omega^2 S^3;\mathbb Z/p)$.

Answer (score 2):

The next two claims completely describe
$H_*(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z})$.
This follows from several sources. For example, from already mentioned
in the answer of Nicholas Kuhn book of Joe Neisendorfer.

**Theorem 1.**
The space $H_*(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is a
primitively generated Hopf algebra such that
$$
H_*(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_p)=
\begin{cases}
\Lambda_p[x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots]\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_p[y_0,y_1,y_2,\cdots]
&\quad\mbox{for}\quad p>2,\\[1mm]
\mathbb{Z}_2[x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots]&\quad\mbox{for}\quad p=2,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\deg(x_r)=2p^r-1,\,\deg(y_r)=2p^{r+1}-2$.
In particular
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{q=0}^\infty\dim H_q\big(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_p\big)\,t^q&=&
\prod_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1+t^{2p^r-1}}{1-t^{2p^{r+1}-2}}\qquad\text{for $p>2$},\\
\sum_{q=0}^\infty\dim H_q\big(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_2\big)\,t^q&=&
\prod_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1-t^{2^{r+1}-1}}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Theorem 2.**
There is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$--modules
$$
H_q(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z})=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}&\text{for $q=0,1$},\\[1mm]
\bigoplus_{p\geqslant 2}\beta_p(H_{q+1}(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_p))&\text{for $q\geqslant 2$},
\end{cases}
$$
where $\beta_p:H_{q+1}(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z}_p)\longrightarrow H_q(\Omega^2S^3;\mathbb{Z})$ is the Bockstein homomorphism corresponding to the exact sequence of coefficients
$0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\times p}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p\longrightarrow 0$
for prime $p\geqslant 2$.
Homomorphisms $\beta_p$ are the graded injective differentiations.
The action of $\beta_p$ is defined by the formulas
$$
\beta_p(x_0)=0,\qquad\beta_2(x_r)=x^2_{r-1},\qquad 
\begin{cases}
\beta_p(x_r)=y_{r-1},\\
\beta_p(y_r)=0
\end{cases}
\quad\text{for $p>2$},
$$
where $r\geqslant 1$.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on but it seems as if this post could do with a few references